# Unit price showing in purchased entity (Item) field

Tags: commerce

Commerce2.x admin/structure/views/view/commerce_cart_form

Field: 
(order_items: Order Item) Order item: Unit price (price)
admin/structure/views/nojs/handler/commerce_cart_form/default/field/unit_price__number

Showing in

Field: (order_items: Order Item) Order item: Purchased entity (item)
admin/structure/views/nojs/handler/commerce_cart_form/default/field/purchased_entity

Is this a bug or configuration problem?

d8.4 Commerce2 updated

[image: shopping cart]

Answer (score 0):

Workaround fix: In structure/views/view/commerce_cart_form Change to hidden field: (order_items: Order Item) Order item: Purchased entity (Item) [hidden]

Add field (order_items: Order Item) Order item: Title (Item) for line item display.

Still researching Purchased entity problem.

[image: cart]